# Found multiple Schemas with namespace 'http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core' and root element name 'ModuleConfiguration'

Tags: dxa, content-porter

I ran into trouble after porting the content from dev to test.The sequence in which I ported the content is Categories and keywords> Schemas> Component template> Component> Page template> pages

**Please find the exact Issue details**

**Error Detail:** Found multiple Schemas with namespace 'http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core' and root element name 'ModuleConfiguration'.

Now it is showing Multiple Module configuration files in the publication

**Error logged in Event Viewer:**

> The number of render failures has exceeded its specified failure limit
> of 0. Found multiple Schemas with namespace
> 'http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core' and root element name
> 'ModuleConfiguration'.  Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing
> Errorcode: 854 User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM StackTrace Information
> Details: at
> Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.Common.TemplateBase.GetSchema(String
> rootElementName, String namespaceUri) at
> Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.Common.TemplateBase.GetActiveModules() at
> Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.PublishConfiguration.Transform(Engine
> engine, Package package) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.AssemblyMediator.Transform(Engine
> engine, Template template, Package package) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.RunTemplate(Engine
> engine, Package package, String templateUri, String className) at
> Tridion.Templating.CSharpTemplate.CSharpSourceTemplate.Transform(Engine
> __engine, Package __package) at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.Transform(Engine
> engine, Template template, Package package) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template
> template, Package package) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package
> package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Compound.CompoundTemplateMediator.Transform(Engine
> engine, Template templateToTransform, Package package) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template
> template, Package package) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package
> package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformPackage(Template
> template, Package package) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformItem(Template
> template, IdentifiableObject itemToRender) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.TemplatingRenderer.Render(ResolvedItem
> resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget
> target, RenderedItem renderedItem, RenderContext renderContext) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderEngine.Render(ResolvedItem
> resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget
> target, RenderContext context) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderEngine.Render(IdentifiableObject
> item, Template template, PublishInstruction instruction,
> PublicationTarget target, RenderContext context) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.RenderComponentPresentationAsRenderedItem(TcmUri
> componentUri, TcmUri componentTemplateUri) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.RenderComponentPresentation(TcmUri
> componentUri, TcmUri componentTemplateUri) at
> Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.RenderComponentPresentations.Transform(Engine
> engine, Package package) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.AssemblyMediator.Transform(Engine
> engine, Template template, Package package) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.RunTemplate(Engine
> engine, Package package, String templateUri, String className) at
> Tridion.Templating.CSharpTemplate.CSharpSourceTemplate.Transform(Engine
> __engine, Package __package) at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.Transform(Engine
> engine, Template template, Package package) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template
> template, Package package) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package
> package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Compound.CompoundTemplateMediator.Transform(Engine
> engine, Template templateToTransform, Package package) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template
> template, Package package) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package
> package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformPackage(Template
> template, Package package) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformItem(Template
> template, IdentifiableObject itemToRender) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.TemplatingRenderer.Render(ResolvedItem
> resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget
> target, RenderedItem renderedItem, RenderContext renderContext) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderEngine.Render(ResolvedItem
> resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget
> target, RenderContext context) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.RenderAndPackage(ResolvedItem
> resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget
> target, List`1 processedItems, PublishTransaction publishTransaction, TransportPackage transportPackage) at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.RenderAndPackage(ResolvedItem resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget target, List`1 processedItems, PublishTransaction publishTransaction,
> TransportPackage transportPackage) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.HandlePublishRequest(PublishTransaction
> publishTransaction) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.ProcessPublishTransaction(PublishTransaction
> publishTransaction) at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Publisher.QueueMessageHandler.HandleMessage()

Comment: To be precise: you now have multiple Module Configuration *Schemas*. But what is your Question, exactly?

Comment: It got resolved now...Thanks for looking into Rick

Comment: @sachinjain, Would be good if you provided your answer and mark it resolved.